# Select from View using Where clause to refer to another database - Unknown Column error

Tags: mysql, view

I am trying to select certain values from a view that I created. The statement is below:

```
SELECT * FROM dashboard.team
WHERE ac2012.acx_users.id = 1;
```

As you can see, there are 2 databases being referenced here:

1. dashboard database, team table
2. ac2012 database, acx_users.id table

ac2012.acx_users.id is the regular expression in the original Create View statement, I'm using that since of course I can't use an ALIAS in a Where clause... however, this is showing an error:

```
Error Code 1054: Unknown column 'ac2012.acx_users.id' in 'where clause'
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work, because I need to reference the other database in this case, but it's not recognizing the database. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: is there a `.` in column name?

Comment: do it  ` `tablename` `  .   `` `column name ` `

Comment: no, dashboard is the database and team is the table. and ac2012 is database, acx_users is table, id is column name

Comment: `ac2012.acx_users.id is the regular expression in the original Create View statement` what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're selecting from a view, the underlying databases aren't visible anymore. You only see what the view presents, as part of the database which the view lives in, so try `WHERE acx_users.id = 1`, or whatever you've aliased that field to in the view definition.

Comment: I tried using the Alias: WHERE 'User ID' = 1 , however it's not returning any results, even though I see many entries where that column has 1 as the value. Is my syntax OK?

Comment: If that's really `'User ID'` with single quotes in your query, then you're actually comparing a **STRING** whose value is 'User ID', not field name. field names use backticks for escaping, not single quotes. anything in single quotes is immediately just a string, and not a table/field/whatever value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM dashboard.team
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ac2012 ON ac2012.CommonColumnName=dashboard.CommonColumnName
    WHERE ac2012.acx_users.id = 1;
```

======================
    Please replace by original column name ...